# Android Ad failed to load 3

Tags: admob, firebase-admob

I am using Rewarded Ads with test ids, however still I am getting error 3.
This looks strange.
Below is the code:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0"

<string name="google_admob_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>

val rewardedCallback = object:RewardedAdLoadCallback(){

}
MobileAds.initialize(this){
   // test id
   RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",    AdRequest.Builder().build(), rewardedCallback)
}
```

This is the error I received when Ads are initialized, no matter what version I use:

```
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcne.<init>(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcoa, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcob, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaas, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbkk, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbka, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzl, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzezz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfac) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:1)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcmu.zza() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:4)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcml com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcmx.zza(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcob, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaas, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbkk, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbka, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzl, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazb, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzezz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfac) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:9)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbsv.<init>(android.content.Context, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcgz, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaas, com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zza) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:3)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbts.zzi(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaas, com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbtr) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:1)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbsx.run() (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:1)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzchd.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:2)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at void com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzche.execute(java.lang.Runnable) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:1)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbtr com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbts.zzf(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaas) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:2)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbtm com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbts.zzg(com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaas) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:4)
2022-02-03 00:45:12.766 2778-2778/com.doppelmate.development I/zygote:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfsm com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbuk.zzb(java.lang.Object) (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@20.5.0:2)​​
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also this problem. Recently my ads was showing, but suddenly it disappear... :/ Without any code changes.